# SAS SD and Percentiles

Tags: sas

I am writing a formula in SAS. I need to use the standard deviation and the percentiles in all of it. But I am not sure how to write that in SAS.

```
data test;
set test1;
if ((the 100th percentile of X)-(99th percentile of X))>(SD of X) then delete;
run;
```

I am just not sure how to write those out in SAS

Comment: Do you have a sample of your data handy? It would really help. 100th percentile, that is a max, right? Are you trying to remove outliers?

Comment: I do not have a public sample of my data :( I am trying to find the outliers for a variable that has 100k+ observations with about 10-100 possible outliers.

Comment: and yeah 100 is the Max…i was just reading the SAS univariate output

Comment: What are you trying to do with this formula? Are you trying to get rid of a particular variable (whole column) or just specific rows? As is, your condition would be the same for all rows and would either (output all rows) or (delete all rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentile and standard deviation are characteristics of the entire data, not just one observation. Your logic seems to suggest you would delete every observation. Presumably you actually want to compare each observation to some feature of the distribution.

The basic approach is to add the percentiles and standard deviation that you want as new variables to your data. You can use `proc univariate` with an `output` statement to calculate the statistics you're interested in and save them to a new data set.

You then merge this back into your original data, so you will now have the variables you need. At that point you can use essentially the same syntax you already have.

This should get you started:

```
data tmp;
    do i=1 to 100;
        x=rannor(123);
        output;
    end;
run;

proc univariate data=tmp noprint;
    var x;
    output out=pctls max=max p99=p99 std=std;
run;

data tmp;
    if _n_=1 then do;
        set pctls;
    end;
    set tmp;

    /* Just making up a condition here */
    if x>p99 then delete;
run;
```